# FTPS conncetion to Fritzbox NAS fails - due to EPSV / PAS port change?

Tags: ftp, nas, port, curl, fritzbox

I am using my FRITZ!Box 3490 with a connected USB HDD as a NAS server. I have configured a certain port (32753) for FTP communication. To ensure a static static servername (u**********u.myfritz.net), I activated and configured myFritz.

The access to the NAS works fine when I access it from my (not locally connected) Laptop via WinSCP.

But when I try to access the NAS through the remote server of my webspace, the connection fails after the EPSV or PAS command.

Here is the terminal:

```
$ curl -v --ftp-pasv --ssl -k -u speedITBackup 'ftp://u**********u.myfritz.net:32753/Backup/Superfein/'
Enter host password for user 'speedITBackup':
*   Trying 92.218.125.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to u**********u.myfritz.net (92.218.125.113) port 32753 (#0)
< 220 FRITZ!Box3490 FTP server ready.
> AUTH SSL
< 501 Use AUTH TLS for secure control connection.
> AUTH TLS
< 234 Authentication method accepted
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=u************u.myfritz.net
*  start date: Dec  9 12:27:41 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 15 12:27:41 2038 GMT
*  issuer: CN=u**********u.myfritz.net
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> USER speedITBackup
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 331 Password required for speedITBackup.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> PASS **************
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 230 User speedITBackup logged in.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> PBSZ 0
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 200 ok
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> PROT P
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 200 Data channel will be secured
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> PWD
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> CWD Backup
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 250 CWD command successful.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> CWD Superfein
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 250 CWD command successful.
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||60770|)
*   Trying 92.218.125.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connecting to 92.218.125.113 (92.218.125.113) port 60770
* connect to 92.218.125.113 port 32753 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to u***********u.myfritz.net port 32753: Connection refused
* Failed EPSV attempt. Disabling EPSV
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
> PASV
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS app data, [no content] (0):
< 227 Entering Passive Mode (92,218,125,113,230,160)
* Skip 92.218.125.113 for data connection, re-use u************u.myfritz.net instead
*   Trying 92.218.125.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*** Connecting to 92.218.125.113 (92.218.125.113) port 59040**
* connect to 92.218.125.113 port 32753 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to u**************u.myfritz.net port 32753: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, [no content] (0):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
curl: (7) Failed to connect to upfamnsqwzodew4u.myfritz.net Port 32753: Connection refused
```

I am not sure what is happening here: With the EPSV and PAS commands, the FRITZ!Box seems to send a new port (60770 / 59040), but then connects to an old one?

Is the problem on server or client side?

Is there a way to get this communication working? Maybe through my FRITZ!Box settings?

With cygwin I attempted to reach my fritzbox and the result is:

```
$ curl -vvv --ftp-pasv --ssl -k -u speedITBackup 'ftp://u********u.myfritz.net:32753/Backup/Superfein/'
Enter host password for user 'speedITBackup':
*   Trying 92.218.125.113:32753...
* connect to 92.218.125.113 port 32753 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to u*************u.myfritz.net port 32753 after 21110 ms: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to u************u.myfritz.net port 32753 after 21110 ms: Timed out
```

Comment: FTP is a sucky protocol that requires 2 connections to be established between tje client and server (data and control connections).  The firewall is likely blocking/not fascilitating the second data connection FTP is trying to negotiate.  Sometimes - depending on your firewall - changing between active and passive mode may help.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried using active mode, but this ends initially in an timeout - due to the firewall settings, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have x-plore installed on my android tv and the fritzbox 3490. And i used an hdd on the usb of the fritzbox smb ftp to watch movies on my tv.

Suddenly out of nowhere i get a timeout from x-plore to the ftp connection. Any ideas why this is happening? I did not change anything in the settings...

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1226330)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have a FRITZ!Box 7520 and got a FTP server running, too. I am accessing it from the local LAN but also from outside. I am using Total Commander + FTP plugin on Android. I am using myFritz, too.

There are 3 types of FTP:

1. unencrypted FTP (uses multiple ports)
2. FTPS (secure FTP, uses multiple ports)
3. SFTP (FTP over SSH, uses one single port)

FRITZ!Box only supports 1 & 2. It's sad because SFTP only requires one port so this is the easiest option when it comes to firewalls.

Your curl command is using FTPS. It can connect but when it tries to list files it fails because it cannot enter passive mode.

This log line is suspicious:

```
*** Connecting to 92.218.125.113 (92.218.125.113) port 59040**
* connect to 92.218.125.113 port 32753 failed: Connection refused
```

It tries to connect on port 59040 and then it says it failed to connect on port 32753. To me that looks like a bug in curl.

Please run:

```
curl --version
```

Mine is 7.74.0. Anything close to this version is acceptable. If you are lucky you only have to update curl.

You can also try these things:

- Use the same curl command in your local LAN and see if it succeeds. You can use cygwin for example to get it running on Windows.
- If it succeeds try it from outside
- Use wget instead of curl

Edit:
You said in the comments, that your hoster blocks outgoing ports between 49152 and 65534. These ports are called dynamic, private or ephemeral as you can read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_port). But I don't know if it makes sense to only block these ports while allowing all others.

The screenshot below shows the FRITZ!Box FTP settings. It seems not to be possible to change the passive mode ports. Only the main port can be changed.

To fix your problem you could:

- switch to another hoster
- use a proxy (curl supports proxies)
- use a Raspberry Pi running an FTP server
- use active mode

[image]

Comment: This is slightly wrong but in ways significant to the question (hence the downvote).  The issue is nothing to do with ftp/ftps/sftp, and SFTP is not ftp over ssh - it uses ssh and ftp like syntax, but its a very diffetent protocol underneath).  You also have not touched on the underlying problem which is passive vs active FTP and the fact that 2 ports are required.

Comment: To clarify, I am using SFTP, not FTP or SFTP. As stated above, I can access my server using the WinSCP Tool - even from outside. The curl version indeed is very old (2018), so I followed your advice and used cygwin with recent curl. But the command runs into a timeout. I should add that the provider is using Plesk and I will ask him to update the curl version. But I am not sure, if this will solve the problem.

Comment: @Marco You aren't using SFTP but FTPS. You can see it because of the multiple ports and FRITZ!Box doesn't support SFTP. WinSCP supports both SFTP and FTPS. Did you try wget? Please add verbose output of cygwin curl and wget to your question.

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo I of course meant FTPS in the first part of my sentence.

Comment: The hoster says the problem is that fritzbox uses a random port between 49152 - 65534. These high ports are closed at the server site for security reasons. Is there a way to change this range in the fritzbox? Should I open another question for that?